# How to add a  checkmark in a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Say I have a small tableview(no scroll) and when a user taps an option, it changes some setting in the app. I used this function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      //some code here
}
```

Now I want to use `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` for the option that is selected, I mean it should display a checkmark in the cell the user selected (and remove checkmark from previously selected option). How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
  for (UITableViewCell *cell in [tableView visibleCells]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  }

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: man! this solved the problem! thats an awesome way to iterate, I didn't know on could do that. thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `accessoryType`property of a `UITableViewCell`.

```
@property(nonatomic) UITableViewCellAccessoryType accessoryType
```

Like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      //code for reusing or init a new cell goes here

      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Comment: thanks man thats one way to do it...can you help me with one little thing...read my comment to above answer. thx.